# In JavaScript, what does the notation /\s*;\s*/ mean?

Tags: javascript, regex, split, separator

In the following example, what does the notation `/\s*;\s*/` mean? It is used as the separator in the `string.split()` command.

```
var names = 'Harry Trump ;Fred Barney; Helen Rigby ; Bill Abel ;Chris Hand ';

console.log(names);

var re = /\s*;\s*/;

var nameList = names.split(re);

console.log(nameList);
```

Comment: It’s a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: `\s` means whitespace `*` means 0 or more times so this will split at any `;` preceded or followed by any amount of whitespace

Comment: Yes, it's a separator in `split()`. It will split the string after match and create and array out of it.

Answer (score 3):

`/\s*;\s*/` is a regular expression and is often used for pattern matching. Your regex (`\s*;\s*`) translates to:

- `\s` matches any white space character [`\r\n\t\f`]
- `*` means apply the previous match between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `;` matches the `;` character literally
- `\s` matches any white space character [`\r\n\t\f`] (same as bullet #1)
- `*` means apply the previous match between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]  (same as bullet #2)

The reason a regular expression is used here rather than a simple string argument to `.split` is because the original string has varying separators between the elements - different combations of spaces and a semi-colon.  There isn't a simple string that could be passed that would find them all - you could use just `;`, but that would leave spaces at the start and/or end of some elements of the array.  The regular expression ensures we match all the variations.

Answer (score 2):

With JavaScript's `.split(separator)` method, you are making an array from a string. `separator` is either a simple string or - more complex - regular expression.

In your example, the regular expression provided is `/\s*;\s*/`. Front and back slashes are just the delimiters saying that it's a regular expression. `\s*;\s*` is your pattern, meaning: any number of whitespace characters (spaces, tabs), followed by a semicolon, followed by any number of whitespace characters. It's a more fancy version of `"my string".split(";")`, because it trims the whitespace before and after the semicolon.

Example:

```
var test1 = "dog;cat;fish".split(";");
// test1 is ["dog", "cat", "fish"]

var test2 = "dog;cat;fish".split(/\s*;\s*/);
// test2 is ["dog", "cat", "fish"]
```

As long as there are no white characters around the semicolon, those two return exactly the same result. But:

```
var test3 = "dog ; cat; fish".split(";");
// test3 is ["dog ", " cat", " fish"]

var test4 = "dog ; cat; fish".split(/\s*;\s*/);
// test4 is ["dog", "cat", "fish"]
```

This time, results of test4 are far more sophisticated, because no spaces are involved.

Answer (score 0):

In [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `\s` meta-character stands for whitespace character.

A whitespace character can be:

A space character
A tab character
A carriage return character
A new line character
A vertical tab character
A form feed character

`*` stands for all.
`;` stands for colon.

The expression here `\s*;\s*` means that any whitespace followed or preceded by `;` will be `split` into an array using [spilit()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly saying, it splits the input string by `;` omitting any amount of spaces all around this `;`.

---

```
var input = "One ;    Two   ;Three   ";
input.split(";")        // returns ["One ", "    Two   ", "Three   "]
input.split(/\s*;\s*/)  // returns ["One", "Two", "Three"]
```